# How to simply pass a variable from server to UI?

Tags: r, server, shiny

I have a shiny app with the server and UI in two different files. The aim is to display a network plot, so I have a list of nodes and a list of edges. 
I would like to add an input that allows the user to select certain nodes.

My UI:

```
ui <- fluidPage(

      visNetworkOutput("network_proxy", height = "400px"), #Plot output
      selectInput(inputId = "selnodes", label = "Nodes selection", choices = , multiple = TRUE) #The input I want
)
```

My server:

```
    nodes <- c(1, 5, 12, 53)
    edges <- data.frame(
       from = c(1,1,5,12,12,53), 
       to = c(5,12,12,12,53, 53),
       stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

    observeEvent(input$generatePlotButton,{
        net <<- generatePlot(nodes,edges)
        output$plotPlot <- renderVisNetwork({net})
    })
```

In my `selectInput` in the UI, I want the proposed values to be the list of nodes that I am using in my plot. So the variable `nodes` that I use on my server.

However, I cannot simply write `choices = nodes` in the parameters, because the UI doesn't know what `nodes` is (remember, it's a variable on the server side).

So I would like to pass my `nodes` variable from server to UI so I can use it to have the list of nodes as choices in my `selectInput`.

What can I do? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is to use renderUI to push the selectInput from server to ui, I like to use this because it is easier to extract choices from the server dataset and you do not need to go back to ui section to change codes. In the example below, I didn't use the updateSelectInput, as I use it more often when it comes to creating a Select All button. 
Here are the codes I have:

```
library(shiny)
library(visNetwork)

ui <- fluidPage(
    visNetworkOutput("plotPlot", height = "400px"), #Plot output
    uiOutput("selnodes"),
    actionButton("Update", "Update")
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output, session) {
    nodes <- data.frame(id = c(1, 5, 12, 53), label = c(1, 5, 12, 53))
    edges <- data.frame(
        from = c(1,1,5,12,12,53), 
        to = c(5,12,12,12,53, 53),
        stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

    output$selnodes <- renderUI({
        selectInput(inputId = "selnodes", label = "Nodes selection", choices = nodes, multiple = TRUE)
    })

    observeEvent(input$Update, {
        ## Update the nodes list 
        nodes <- data.frame(id = input$selnodes, label = input$selnodes)
        net <- visNetwork(nodes,edges)
        output$plotPlot <- renderVisNetwork({net})
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Hadn't thought about this. Thank you, great idea! I mark it as solved because I think it's more universal than the (very good) answer provided by arg0naut91, and it might help other people.

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

```
ui <- fluidPage(

  visNetworkOutput("network_proxy", height = "400px"), #Plot output
  selectInput(inputId = "selnodes", label = "Nodes selection", choices = "", multiple = TRUE)
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  nodes <- c(1, 5, 12, 53)
  edges <- data.frame(
    from = c(1,1,5,12,12,53), 
    to = c(5,12,12,12,53, 53),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

  observeEvent(input$generatePlotButton,{
    net <<- generatePlot(nodes,edges)
    output$plotPlot <- renderVisNetwork({net})
  })

  observe({
    updateSelectInput(session, "selnodes", choices = nodes)
  })

}
```

Comment: I didn't know `updateSelectInput`was a thing! Thanks!

Comment: please dont put any outputs into observe, as you might have memory leaks

Comment: @PorkChop that's a separate issue, but OP can take note